# Como ler o xml para objeto com XStream

Tags: java

Tenho um relacionamento de 1 para n de produto para historico , ou seja, um produto tem vários meses/historicos. Como ler o seguinte xml para Objeto?

```
<produto>
  <descricao>PAVESINO 800X15</descricao>
  <valor>2.30</valor>
  <historicos>
    <historico>
      <mesesHistoricos>2009-12-21 18:40:56.281 UTC</mesesHistoricos>
      <quantidade>6735</quantidade>
    </historico>
    <historico>
      <mesesHistoricos>2010-01-21 18:40:56.283 UTC</mesesHistoricos>
      <quantidade>5940</quantidade>
    </historico>
    <historico>
     <mesesHistoricos>2010-02-21 19:40:56.283 UTC</mesesHistoricos>
      <quantidade>4824</quantidade>
    </historico>
    <historico>
      <mesesHistoricos>2010-02-21 19:40:56.283 UTC</mesesHistoricos>
      <quantidade>7869</quantidade>
    </historico>
    <historico>
      <mesesHistoricos>2010-02-21 19:40:56.283 UTC</mesesHistoricos>
      <quantidade>8152</quantidade>
    </historico>
  </historicos>
</produto>
```

Segue a tabela de Produto :

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name = "produto")
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = Produto.ALL, query = "Select a FROM Produto a"),
        @NamedQuery(name = Produto.COUNT, query = "select count(a) from Produto a"),
        @NamedQuery(name = Produto.DESCRICAO, query = "from Produto where upper(descricao) = :descricao") })
public class Produto implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public final static String ALL = "produto.populaproduto";
public final static String COUNT = "produto.countprodutoTotal";
public final static String DESCRICAO = "produto.descricao";

private Long codigo;

private Integer Version;

private String codigoProduto;

private String descricao;

private BigDecimal valor;

private List<Historico> historicos = new ArrayList<>();


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "produto", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public List<Historico> getHistoricos() {
    return historicos;
}

public void setHistoricos(List<Historico> historicos) {
    this.historicos = historicos;
}

public Produto() {
}

public Produto(String descricao, BigDecimal valor) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
    this.valor = valor;
}

@Version
public Integer getVersion() {
    return Version;
}

public void setVersion(Integer version) {
    Version = version;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Long getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

@NotBlank
@Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
public String getCodigoProduto() {
    return codigoProduto;
}

public void setCodigoProduto(String codigoProduto) {
    this.codigoProduto = codigoProduto;
}

public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao == null ? null : descricao.toUpperCase().trim();

}

@NotBlank
@Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
}

@Column(name = "valor", nullable = false, precision = 10, scale = 2)
public BigDecimal getValor() {
    return valor;
}

public void setValor(BigDecimal valor) {
    this.valor = valor;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((codigo == null) ? 0 : codigo.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Produto other = (Produto) obj;
    if (codigo == null) {
        if (other.codigo != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!codigo.equals(other.codigo))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

}

Segue a tabela Historico :

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name = "historico")
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = Historico.ALL, query = "Select a FROM Historico a"),
        @NamedQuery(name = Historico.COUNT, query = "select count(a) from Historico a") })
public class Historico implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public final static String ALL = "Historico.populaHistorico";
public final static String COUNT = "Historico.countHistoricoTotal";
public final static String DESCRICAO = "Historico.descricao";

private Long codigo;

private Integer Version;

private Date mesesHistoricos;

private Integer quantidade;

private Produto produto;

@Version
public Integer getVersion() {
    return Version;
}

public void setVersion(Integer version) {
    Version = version;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Long getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}


@NotNull
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "meses_historicos", nullable = false)
public Date getMesesHistoricos() {
    return mesesHistoricos;
}

public void setMesesHistoricos(Date mesesHistoricos) {
    this.mesesHistoricos = mesesHistoricos;
}

@Column(nullable = false, length = 3)
public Integer getQuantidade() {
    return quantidade;
}

public void setQuantidade(Integer quantidade) {
    this.quantidade = quantidade;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_produto", nullable = false)
public Produto getProduto() {
    return produto;
}

public void setProduto(Produto produto2) {
    this.produto = produto2;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((codigo == null) ? 0 : codigo.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Historico other = (Historico) obj;
    if (codigo == null) {
        if (other.codigo != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!codigo.equals(other.codigo))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Você consegue converter o `XML` para o objeto `Produto` utilizando o `XStream` desta forma:

```
public Produto xmlToProduto(String xml) {
    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.alias("produto", Produto.class);
    xstream.alias("historico", Historico.class);
    return (Produto) xstream.fromXML(xml);
}
```

O comando `alias` diz para seu `xstream` que o atributo "produto" corresponde ao objeto Produto.class e o atributo "historico" corresponde ao objeto Historico.class, com esses parâmetros definidos basta apenas você fazer a conversão do xml para Object com o comando `fromXML`

Você pode encontrar um conteúdo bem legal sobre `XStream` no [devmedia](http://www.devmedia.com.br/trabalhando-com-a-biblioteca-xstream-em-java/27194)